# CancellationToken.Register execution context

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Given the code snippet below, I would like to make sure, that when somebody signals the cancellation token source ***cts***, the *win.Close()* method should be called in the _uiContext context (GUI context captured earlier).

Is this the guaranteed right way to do this?

```
CancellationTokenRegistration ctReg;
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

var promise = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
                var win = new UserView(tcs); // passed in

                win.DataContext = someViewModel;

                   ctReg= cts.Token.Register(() =>
                    {
                        win.Close(); // this should run in _uiContext

                    }, true);


                    win.Show();

                return await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);

  }, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, _uiContext).Unwrap();
```

Comment: What's `_uiContext`?

Comment: It is the variable holding the captured UI context earlier (TaskScheduler.FromSynchronizationContext())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed this callback will run on the captured context since it is passed to `StartNew` and captured by passing `true` to `Register`.

However, that's pretty complicated. You can invoke that callback straight onto a control which is clearer:

```
win.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, () => win.Close());
```

Note: `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` is somewhat useless here, if you're scheduling that task on the UI thread. This is mostly used when scheduling to the default `TaskScheduler`